# Oracle Inner join on multiple tables returning null values

Tags: oracle

I am working on a sql inner join query which should return MAX elements from other tables. Tables B, C, D, E might be empty. In that case null should also be printed in output.

This is what I tried.

```
SELECT A.INDEX, A.CODE, MAX(B.DAY), MAX(C.TIMESTAMP), MAX(D.TIMESTAMP) 
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B 
INNER JOIN C
INNER JOIN D
INNER JOIN E
ON A.INDEX = B.INDEX
ON A.INDEX = C.INDEX
ON A.INDEX = D.INDEX
ON A.INDEX = E.INDEX AND E.FUNCTION = 0;
```

Table definitions:

```
A
-------
INDEX NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
CODE NOT NULL VARCHAR2(16)

B
--------
INDEX NUMBER(10)
DAY NUMBER(10)

C
---------
INDEX NUMBER(10)
TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP(6)

D
---------
INDEX NUMBER(10)
TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP(6)

E
----------
INDEX NUMBER(10)
FUNCTION NUMBER(5)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that case, consider doing a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead like

```
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B
```

So for your case

```
SELECT A.INDEX, A.CODE, MAX(B.DAY), MAX(C.TIMESTAMP), MAX(D.TIMESTAMP) 
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON A.INDEX = B.INDEX
LEFT JOIN C ON A.INDEX = C.INDEX
LEFT JOIN D ON A.INDEX = D.INDEX
LEFT JOIN E ON A.INDEX = E.INDEX 
AND E.FUNCTION = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked. I am looking for only matching elements from table E. I don't care about B,C,D. If records are present in B,C,D MAX() records should be returned otherwise null. 

I modified query as below. It worked too.

SELECT A.INDEX, A.CODE, MAX(B.DAY), MAX(C.TIMESTAMP), MAX(D.TIMESTAMP) 
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON A.INDEX = B.INDEX
LEFT JOIN C ON A.INDEX = C.INDEX
LEFT JOIN D ON A.INDEX = D.INDEX
INNER JOIN E ON A.INDEX = E.INDEX 
AND E.FUNCTION = 0;